# css clearing an absolutely positioned div

Tags: html, css

I have a page with divs 250px x 250px which are all positioned absolutely, when one of these divs are opened an ajax call is made which expands the div to show all its contents, these divs are restricted to 600px in width but can be any height depending on info being presented so when a div has alot of content it seems to stretch over my footer which is understandable due to the fact that the widgets hovering on the page.

My question though is can I somehow set my footer to clear this large widget as it seems to be stretching over it?

Comment: have you tried clear: both; ?


can you post the html you are having a problem with ?

Comment: actually I've just checked out this problem and realised that the footer moves to allow the div to expand in every browser except ff?

Comment: jsfiddle or live demo would help. You'll have to mesure the expadned div size, and add appropriate margin/padding to the footer or, container that holds your expanded div.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no way of clearing an absolutely positioned div, absolutely positioned divs are taken completely out of the document flow. You can have a look at using a [sticky footer](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/) which should keep your footer at the very bottom of the page which should visually fix up your page as the footer will no longer abruptly end.

However unless you restructure your HTML or use some javascript to check the height of the div, you wont be able to have the footer appear nicely underneath the div using pure CSS.